# ASP .net C# SqlConnection Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a window hosting in 1and1.com. I try to connect the database with following code, but I get the error message. You can view error message here http://www.s499993321.onlinehome.us/Default.aspx

Does any one know happen? How to connect the database?

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost; Database=db500148144; User Id=dbo500148144; Password=12345abc"))
        {

            cn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM people", cn);

            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
            rdr.Read();
            Response.Write(rdr[0].ToString());

        }
       // Response.Write("How");
    }
```

Comment: It's SQL Server or MySql? SqlConnection, SqlCommand and SqlDataReader only work with SQL Server.

Comment: sql express on the same machine?

Comment: please turn off customErrors to show the error.. `<customErrors mode="Off"/>` in web.config

Comment: Ok, you've tagged MySql.

Comment: I already turn off customerErrors. I get the Error Message: "Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached."

Comment: I think I get it now... the server is not in localhost... 1and1 is so suck!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: sql servers are not very often on localhost ;)

Answer (score 0):

If SQL server is on the same machine use

```
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Server=.\MSSQLSERVER2012; Database=db500148144; User Id=dbo500148144; Password=12345abc")
```

MSSQLSERVER2012 is the instance name. One way to find out the name is by opening services.msc and checking the name of the sql server service running on your machine. for me it was 
"SQL server(MSSQLSERVER2012)"

Answer (score -1):

There is issue in your web.config file, Remove CustomeErrro tag  from web.config , and try.

Comment: Shouldn't it be a comment.?